# search in rails with sunspot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I'm using sunspot for search and it work fine, and i have implemented a fecet search this is my view for facet

```
<% for row in @search.facet(:company_id).rows %>
  <li>
    <% if params[:company_id].blank? %>
      <%= link_to row.instance.name, :company_id => row.value %> <%= row.count %>
    <% else %>
      <strong><%= row.instance.name %></strong> (<%= link_to "remove", :month => nil %>)
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

and this is the controller

```
  def search

    @search = Sunspot.search(Job) do

        fulltext params[:query]
        with(:company_id, params[:company_id]) if params[:company_id].present?
        facet :company_id , :limit => 5
        paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)

    end

    @jobs = @search.results


    respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :action => "search" }
    end
  end
```

but instead of using link_to in view i want to use check box to have something similar to this [image]

i have tried this solution but it is wrong `<%= check_box_tag row.instance.name, :company_id => row.value %> <%= row.count %>`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the use of checkbox is because you don't want to refresh the page.
This means that you will have to pull this data in by ajax.

One way to go about this would be:

1. Bind a refreshResults function with checkbox
2. In the refreshResults function do an ajax query and in your rails action render a partial which gives the updated results.
3. Success callback in ajax callback will update the results div on the page.

Will add more details and code samples if you think this sounds like the right approach for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need create simple form like this:

```
<%= form_tag request.original_url, method: :get do %>
  <% for row in @search.facet(:company_id).rows %>
    <li> 
      <%= label nil, row.instance.name %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'company_ids[]', row.value, Array.wrap(params[:company_ids]).include?(row.value.to_s) %>         
      <%= row.count %>
    </li>
  <% end %> 
  <li> 
     <%= submit_tag 'Send' %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

And modify search query in controller:

```
...
with(:company_ids, params[:company_ids]) if params[:company_ids].present?
...
```

If require search interactively, You need append ajax request in frontend and json (or other format) response in backend.